# Need Clarifications about Jhipster Entity Relationships

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

1. one to many
2. many to one
3. many to many
4. one to one

Need some more clarifications about them. Referred that in many sites but cant able to get the perfect definitions. thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read http://jhipster.github.io/managing-relationships/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explain you these conceptual data modeling relations on the example.

- **One to many (1:n)** means one entity can work with more ones.

  - Example: One employer can hire more employees.
- **Many to one (n:1)** works same as the one above from the different view.
- **One to one (1:1)** means one entity can work only with the other one.

  - Example: Every employee can work only with one computer
- **Many to many (n:m)**  means there is a combination of relations between entities.

  - Example: Each customer belongs to more employees and one employee serves for one or more customers.
  - Usually in database systems there will be created a new table holding these relations in case of m:n.

Comment: Thanks Nik, Thats what am Expected.

Comment: Welcome, glad it helps :)

Comment: Hi Nik , i have a Another doubt, What is the use of those relationships between those entities ? can you explain me about that ?

Comment: It's too wide to answer. I suggest you to learn first fundamentals of Java and databases, and then start exploring more. Try to download few examples to know how it works.